# Can't find autocomplete on MELPA

Tags: emacsclient, package-repositories

So I'm following this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTUE03LnaXA) and when I go to `M-x package-list-packages` there is no auto-complete in the directory.

```
; start pacakage.el with emacs
(require 'package)
; add Melpa to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa", "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
; initialise package.el
(package-initialize)
```

This is my `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: Should be `'("melpa" . "http://melpa..")`, dot, not comma

Comment: @npostavs: Please post that as an answer. OP: Please consider accepting that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements of `package-archives` should be conses, which can be written as [dotted pairs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html):

```el
; add Melpa to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

Commas are never used in lisp code except when paired with [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).